# Check if object in warehouse moved out, stayed or is new. Based on two variables

Tags: mysql, sql, difference, warehouse

```
    ids yesterday   date        ids today       date

s   01516047894532  07.09.2016  01516047894532  08.09.2016  
s   01516047894533  07.09.2016  01516047894533  08.09.2016  
m   01516047894524  07.09.2016  01516047894534  08.09.2016  
m   01516047894525  07.09.2016  01516047894535  08.09.2016  
m   01516047894526  07.09.2016  01516047894536  08.09.2016  
s   01516047894537  07.09.2016  01516047894537  08.09.2016  
s   01516047894538  07.09.2016  01516047894538  08.09.2016  
n                               01516047894539  08.09.2016
```

I am trying to find out if a object moved out of my warehouse, based on a unique ID and a date. My main problem is that all this data is stored in one table. I made a simple example above. First of all (s=stayed, m=moved out, n=new in warehouse). I need to find all objects that moved out. I tried to find all objects that actually stayed and than use a NOT IN, but I cant add the new objects to it.
That is my attempt:

```
select y.id
from warehouse y
INNER JOIN warehouse t
ON (y.date != t.date AND y.id= t.id)
```

I am missing the 01516047894539 id, I am sure there is a simple way, but I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use y.date = null condition

```
select y.id
   from warehouse y
      JOIN warehouse t
      ON y.date != t.date AND
      y.id= t.id AND
      y.id= null ;
```

This will help you

Comment: This returns nothing, I also tried OR y.id= null, but its the same result as my old solution. I checked the inner join without any conditions and there is no null field at all, maybe beacuse its the same table ?

Comment: instead of providing inner join, just specify join

Comment: That also does not work, but I also think that the expression "y.id= t.id AND y.id= null" ; can never be true.